# KeyError at /shops/profile/mannu

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Hello django developers !. I hope you all are fine.. :)
Well here i want to get the `shop_owner` from `shop detail view` to the `get context data` function so i can count the total products of that particular shop..

models.py

```
class ShopProfile(models.Model):

    shop_owner = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='shop_profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shop_address = models.CharField(_("shop address"), max_length=255)
```

views.py

```
class ShopProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model = ShopProfile
    template_name='shops/shop_profile.html'

    def get_context_data(self,*args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ShopProfileDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        user = context['shop_owner'] #getting error here 
        context["products_count"] = Product.objects.filter(product_owner=user).count()
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

If the KeyError is raised from a failed dictionary key lookup in your own code, you can use . get() to return either the value found at the specified key or a default value.

Comment: I think this answer should be a comment. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Well I fixed it, By printing the context variable above the error line, in my case

```
print('context data',context)
user = context['shop_owner'] #getting error here
```

It will return some fields in the terminal then You can simply get any data from that context. :)